# Laravel get route name from given URL

Tags: php, laravel, routes

In Laravel, we can get route name from current URL via this:

```
Route::currentRouteName()
```

But, how can we get the route name from a specific given URL?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: @TunaMaxx I am trying to get the route name from a given URL, not current URL.

Comment: No, I totally get it, but I don't understand *why* you need to do it. Essentially you are looking to reverse engineer the routes.php file.

Comment: That's not a good pattern

Comment: If you could explain why, we can find another way

Answer (score 38):

A very easy way to do it **`Laravel 5.2`**

```
app('router')->getRoutes()->match(app('request')->create('/qqq/posts/68/u1'))->getName()
```

It outputs my Route name like this **`slug.posts.show`**

**Update**: For method like **POST**, **PUT** or **DELETE** you can do like this

```
app('router')->getRoutes()->match(app('request')->create('/qqq/posts/68/u1', 'POST'))->getName()//reference https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/Request.php#L309
```

Also when you run `app('router')->getRoutes()->match(app('request')->create('/qqq/posts/68/u1', 'POST'))` this will return `Illuminate\Routing\Route` instance where you can call multiple useful public methods like `getAction`, `getValidators` etc. Check the source https://github.com/illuminate/routing/blob/master/Route.php for more details.

Answer (score 12):

None of the solutions above worked for me.

This is the correct way to match a route with the URI:

```
$url = 'url-to-match/some-parameter';

$route = collect(\Route::getRoutes())->first(function($route) use($url){
   return $route->matches(request()->create($url));
});
```

The other solutions perform bindings to the container and can screw up your routes...

Comment: Thanks, this is the only solution that work without breaking some routes, especially route with parameters

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this can be done with out-of-the-box Laravel.  Also remember that not all routes in Laravel are named, so you probably want to retrieve the route object, not the route name.

One possible solution would be to extend the default `\Iluminate\Routing\Router` class and add a public method to your custom class that uses the protected `Router::findRoute(Request $request)` method.

A simplified example:

```php
class MyRouter extends \Illuminate\Routing\Router {

    public function resolveRouteFromUrl($url) {
        return $this->findRoute(\Illuminate\Http\Request::create($url));
    }
}
```

This *should* return the route that matches the URL you specified, but I haven't actually tested this.

Note that if you want this new custom router to replace the built-in one, you will likely have to also create a new ServiceProvider to register your new class into the IoC container instead of the default one.

You could adapt the ServiceProvider in the code below to your needs:

https://github.com/jasonlewis/enhanced-router

Otherwise if you just want to manually instantiate your custom router in your code as needed, you'd have to do something like:

```
$myRouter = new MyRouter(new \Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher());
$route = $myRouter->resolveRouteFromUrl('/your/url/here');
```

Answer (score 5):

It can be done without extending the default `\Iluminate\Routing\Router` class.

```
    Route::dispatchToRoute(Request::create('/your/url/here'));
    $route = Route::currentRouteName();
```

If you call `Route::currentRouteName()` after `dispatchToRoute` call, it will return current route name of dispatched request.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 10

```php
<?php
\Route::getRoutes()->match(Request::create($url));
```