# Laravel get url's route name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

Is it possible to get the route name of a given URL in Laravel 5? The `Route::currentRouteName()` is just getting the route name of the CURRENT url. Instead, how can I get the route name of a given url? Something like `Route::getRouteName('http://example.com/users')`?

Comment: I think this will be helpful to you :) 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24582922/laravel-get-route-name-from-given-url

Comment: above comment is also  duplicate :) :p

Comment: @Alupotha These comments (*"Possible duplicate: [url]"*) are automatically added when someone flags a question as duplicate