# Previous route name in Laravel 5.1-5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I try to find name of previous route in Laravel 5.1.
With:

```
{!! URL::previous() !!}
```

I get the route url, but I try to get route name like I get for current page:

```
{!! Route::current()->getName() !!}
```

My client wont a different text for *Thank you page*, depends on from page  (*Register page* or *Contact page*) user go to *Thank you page*. I try with:

```
{!! Route::previous()->getName() !!}
```

But that didn't work. I try to get something like:

```
@if(previous-route == 'contact')
  some text
@else
  other text
@endif
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Here what work for me. I find this answer and this question and modify it to work in my case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36476224/2807381

```
@if(app('router')->getRoutes()->match(app('request')->create(URL::previous()))->getName() == 'public.contact')
    Some text
@endif
```

**Update for 5.8 version** by [Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2134999/robert)

```
app('router')->getRoutes()->match(app('request')->create(url()->previous()))->getName()
```

Comment: If also implementing Route::fallback, Laravel will always return this as the matched route. Anyone has a workaround for this?

Comment: `app('router')->getRoutes()->match(app('request')->create(url()->previous()))->getName()` This is the working example in 5.8

Answer (score 14):

Simply you can do this to achieve it. I hope it helps

**In Controller:**

```
$url = url()->previous();
$route = app('router')->getRoutes($url)->match(app('request')->create($url))->getName();

if($route == 'RouteName') {
    //Do required things
 }
```

**In blade file**

```
@php
 $url = url()->previous();
 $route = app('router')->getRoutes($url)->match(app('request')->create($url))->getName();
@endphp

@if($route == 'RouteName')
   //Do one task
@else
  // Do another task
@endif
```

Answer (score 9):

You can't get route name of previous page, so your options are:

1. Check previous URL instead of a route name.
2. Use [sessions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session). First, save route name:

   ```
   session()->flash('previous-route', Route::current()->getName());
   ```

Then check if session has `previous-route`:

```
@if (session()->has(`previous-route`) && session(`previous-route`) == 'contacts')
    Display something
@endif
```

3. Use `GET` parameters to pass route name.

If I were you, I'd use sessions or would check previous URL.

Answer (score 4):

I've created a helper function like this.

```
/**
 * Return whether previous route name is equal to a given route name.
 *
 * @param string $routeName
 * @return boolean
 */
function is_previous_route(string $routeName) : bool
{
    $previousRequest = app('request')->create(URL::previous());

    try {
        $previousRouteName = app('router')->getRoutes()->match($previousRequest)->getName();
    } catch (\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException $exception) {
        // Exception is thrown if no mathing route found.
        // This will happen for example when comming from outside of this app.
        return false;
    }

    return $previousRouteName === $routeName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Route::getRoutes()->match(request()->create(url()->previousPath()))->getName();