# Laravel 5 previous request path

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Is there any built-in method in Laravel to get the path of the previous URL?

I know about `url()->previous();` but i only want to get previous path.
Also, I can extract previous path from the previous URL. But I would like to know if there is any built-in method in Laravel.

Comment: But that is the built in method, there is no other!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Previous route name in Laravel 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690202/previous-route-name-in-laravel-5-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Laravel 5.3**

I've gone through same problem and I had searched for the same thing but i end up writing a code to manually extract path from previous URL.
Therefore I think there is no such method provided by Laravel(till 5.3) to get only path of previous URL.