# Redirect user to same page after login in a specific page

Tags: php, laravel

I have this route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
    Route::get('/congress/create', [
        'uses' => 'CongressController@create',
        'as'   => 'congress.create'
    ]);
  }
```

When user acessses this url:

```
<li><a href="{!! route('congress.create') !!}"> Create Congress </a></li>
```

The user goes to "http://project.test/login", because the user needs to be authenticated to access the congressc reate page. When the user is authenticated he is redirected to the "http://project.test/congress/create". So this part is working fine.

**Issue:**

But then I have a link so the user can access the congress details page:

```
<a href="{{route('congress.show', ['id' => $congress->id, 'slug' => $congress->slug])}}">More congress details</a>
```

The user can access the congress details page "http://project.test/congress/1/congress-test" without being authenticated. The route is:

```
Route::get('/congress/{id}/{slug?}', [
    'uses' => 'FrontController@show',
    'as'   =>'congresses.show'
]);
```

Then in the congress details page there is a form with this route:

```
 <form method="post" action="{{route('congresses.registration', ['id' => $congress->id, 'slug' => $congress->slug])}}">
```

Route for this form:

```
Route::post('/congress/{id}/{slug?}/registration', [
    'uses' => 'RegistrationController@storeQuantity',
    'as'   =>'congresses.registration'
]);
```

In the storeQuantity method are stored the selected quantities by the user for each congress ticket type and then the user is redirected to the registration page:

`return view('congresses.registration')->with('selectedRtypes', $selectedRtypes)`;

So when the user submits the form he goes to "http://project.test/event/1/congress-test/registration". In this page if the user is not authenticated it appears this message:

```
@if(!\Auth::check())
    <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
        <span>
            Already have an account? 
            <a data-toggle="modal" 
            data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg" 
            href="">Login.</a>
        </span>
    </div>
@endif
```

If user clicks in Login, it appears a modal so the user can insert the email and password and if login with success the modal should close and he should be redirected to the same registration page.

**Issue**: The issue is that if the user logins with success in this page "http://project.test/congress/1/congress-test/registration" with the form in the modal he is redirected to the "Create congress" page ("http://project.test/congress/create") instead of staying in the registration page ("http://project.test/congress/1/congress-test/registration"). Do you know how to correct this issue?

**LoginController:**

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;


    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {

        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectTo);

    }
}
```

Example of the context:
[image]

Comment: in your authenticated method, check the previous request url is equal to `route('congresses.registration')`. If yes redirect to `route('congresses.registration')`

Comment: Thanks, but like this " if (URL::previous() === URL::route('congress.create')) {
            return redirect(route('congress.create'));
        } else if(URL::previous() === URL::route('congresses.registration')){
            return redirect(route('congresses.registration'));
        }
        else{
            return redirect()->intended($this->redirectTo);

        }" its not working.

Comment: It appears "Missing required parameters for [Route: congresses.registration] [URI: congress/{id}/{slug?}/registration.

Comment: The error it seems that is in the else if. Do you know how to get the congress id and slug to use "else if(URL::previous() === URL::route('congresses.registration')){ return redirect(route('congresses.registration',['id' => $congress->id, 'slug' => $congress->slug])); }"?

Comment: What happens if you click the next button at the bottom of the registration page without logging in? If the reason you are not redirecting to the login page for unauthenticated users after the congress page is that you want to store the values from the congress page then just have a route specifically to store the values like /congress/{id}/{slug?}/store that then redirects to the registration page which can then be added to the auth group meaning unauthenticated users will be asked to sign in.

Comment: In the congress details page (first screen) if the user is not loged and select the quantities and click next he goes to the login.blade.php because the route to the registration.blade.php is inside the auth middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

In your authenticated method, check the previous request url is equal to route('congresses.registration'). If yes redirect to route('congresses.registration') with parameters.

LoginController:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;


    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        //check if the previous page route name is 'congresses.registration'
        if(Route::getRoutes()->match(Request::create(\URL::previous()))->getName() == 'congresses.registration') {
            //redirect to previous page with parameters
            return redirect(Request::create(\URL::previous())->getRequestUri());
        }
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectTo);

    }
}
```

Hope it helps.. Let me know the results..

Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690202/previous-route-name-in-laravel-5-1-5-6)

Comment: Thanks, but after the user login is redireted to "http://project.test/home". I also change tihs "protected $redirectTo = '/home'; to "    protected $redirectTo = '/';" but same issue.

Comment: can you explain the scenario? when do you have problems? Isn't my answer works?

Comment: The user accesses the homepage, in the homepage are presented soem congresses, the user click in one congress link "see more details", he is redirected to the congress details page. In this congress details page the user select the quantiteis for each ticket type and click "Next" and the user is redirected to the registration page.

Comment: In the registration page there is the link that opens a modal so the user can login. So the user click in login and the modal opens the user introduce his email and password click in "Confirm" and is redirected to "project.test/home" instead of being redirected to the same page: "http://project.test/congress/1/congress-test/registration".

Comment: Isn't the modal inside the '"project.test/congress/1/congress-test/registration"' page? Also what happens when my changes are introduced in the login controller? still the same?

Comment: The modal is in the registration page '"project.test/congress/1/congress-test/registration". With your code its redirected to "project.test/home" instead of close the modal and stay in the same page.  With only "        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectTo);" the user is redirected to "http://project.test/" instead of "http://project.test/home".

Comment: please put `dd(Route::getRoutes()->match(Request::create(\URL::previous()))->getName())` inside the `authenticated` method. {as the first statement, before if) and show me the result.

Comment: It appeared "Method getRoutes does not exist.".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168997/discussion-between-ab-ab-and-adamk).

Answer (score 1):

Put the route `Route::post('/congress/{id}/{slug?}/registration')` above `Route::get('/congress/{id}/{slug?}')`

As you log in with a modal, the underlying page stays 'static'. It may hold 'old' information. What if you add a condition to the `authenticated` function where you check if the route is equal to `'congresses.registration'` and set `$redirectTo` this page manually.

As a side note, it is better not to add anything after conditions ({slug?}) unless the slug is always there. Then you can as well drop the '?'. I know it's a GET and a POST so there is probably no confusion. Make sure your slug can not be the word 'registration' by adding it the the `$reserved` array in `config/sluggable.php`.

Comment: Thanks, but like this " if (URL::previous() === URL::route('congress.create')) { return redirect(route('congress.create')); } else if(URL::previous() === URL::route('congresses.registration')){ return redirect(route('congresses.registration')); } else{ return redirect()->intended($this->redirectTo); }" its not working.

Comment: It appears "Missing required parameters for [Route: congresses.registration] [URI: congress/{id}/{slug?}/registration.

Comment: The error it seems that is in the else if. Do you know how to get the congress id and slug to use "else if(URL::previous() === URL::route('congresses.registration')){ return redirect(route('congresses.registration',['id' => $congress->id, 'slug' => $congress->slug])); }"?

Comment: It is not previous, it is current. If I were you, just add the middleware to the controller function route. After the login, the visitor will be rerouted to the previous page exactly where you want it. Using a modal to login looks fancy, but unfortunately it creates a new level of complexity.

Comment: Thanks, but so without the modal login how the code in the login  authenticated method should be?

Comment: It appears "Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException" with "protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {




        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectTo);



    }"

Comment: `Route::post('/congress/{id}/{slug?}/registration', [
    'uses' => 'RegistrationController@storeQuantity',
    'as'   =>'congresses.registration',
    'middleware' => 'auth'
]);`

BUT. I have never added a middleware to a POST. Your situation is unusual. It seems, the form can be accessed/viewed, but to actually post the data, the user has to be logged in. You can try it. If it doesn't work, or the posted data gets lost along the way, try to rework the approach. You could for instance, load the html-form after the user logged on the modal. If you still want the login modal present.