# how can i know or set id for any HTTP request in Laravel

Tags: laravel, http, tcp, request, tracker

I want to analyze how the user works on the website. For example, he opens the pages of the site in order:

`-> main page -> product page -> detail page -> ...`

That's why I use the "tracker" system and send an HTTP request to the server on every page of the site. It is very difficult to compare requests when there are so many in the moment.

but i think now if i can know or set id for HTTP requests (KeepAlive connections) is so well.

someone can show a helpful way for me.

tnx

Comment: not sure but google analytics might be useful for you.

Comment: Mr. Kenneth thank you for help but i want set our tracker system.

Comment: If so, then I could suggest you use laravel middleware where you can store user accessing pages. You could also store previous route name and current route name(Storing in logs or DB will be bloated very fast. I suggest you store this in nosql like mongodb.)

Comment: i think this is a good idea, thank you and i will try this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by using middleware

Create a middleware to track routes:

```
php artisan make:middleware LogRouteMiddleware
```

### LogRouteMiddleware

```
class LogRouteMiddleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $currentRoute = url()->current();// or route name: Route::currentRouteName();
        $previousRoute = url()->previous(); //or route name: app('router')->getRoutes()->match(app('request')->create(url()->previous()))->getName()

        // Store them in DB or Logs. up to you
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

### app\Http\Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    // other middleware entries
    'log.route' => \App\Http\Middleware\LogRouteMiddleware::class,
];
```

### web.php\api.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['log.route']], function() {
    ... // all routes you want to track
});
```

[Accessing current route](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#accessing-the-current-route)

[Accessing previous route](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40690569)

[URL method](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-url)

Comment: Did not test but this should give you something to start with. My usage of current and previous route name might be wrong though but it should give you a start.