# How to get previous route name in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to get previous route name in Laravel 5.8. This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40690569/16735772) works perfectly when I use Virtual Host but in direct url like (125.125.125.125/project_folder/public) does not because NotFoundHttpException is thrown.

With Virtual Host, `$request->create(url()->previous())` creates a request with pathInfo and requestUri using relative url, for example, `my_profile/2` but without Virtual Host, those attributes have different value, like `project_folder/public/my_profile/2`.

I don't need to redirect back, just know previous route name to check. For example:

```
if ($previous_route == 'show_name') {
   //do something
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57339956/14344959 checkout this answer. I hope this one helps to you

Comment: Thanks for the hint but it doesn't work either. The result of callback is null when I don't use Virtual Host. It seems it's taking project_folder/public as part of relative URL, so this url is not found in route list.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to get the previous route name:

```
Route::getRoutes()->match(
    Request::create(URL::previous())
)->getName();
```

You can make a helper or blade directive to make it easier to access.

Comment: This is the answer I commented in my question that works when I use Virtual Host, but not using direct url (125.125.125.125/project_folder/public)

Comment: Thanks for the hint but it doesn't work either. The result of callback is null when I don't use Virtual Host. It seems it's taking project_folder/public as part of relative URL, so this url is not found in route list.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know anymore. Another way is you can put the current route name in the session .