# Unable to receive POST data in "/" route with Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel

This is driving me crazy, and I can't find any clue in the web.

With Laravel 10, I can't get POST data in the route pointing to root folder. This is my route:

```
Route::match(['GET', 'POST'], '/', [Controllers\TurnoController::class, 'today'])->name('today');
```

It only happens with this route. If I modify / to /test, it works without problem.
Weird thing is, it works perfect in dev PC with wamp, and works too in a raspbian server with apache.

In production machine, it won't work. I must say that in production, I'm running the project in a subfolder, with a symlink public -> public_html/app/project.

Any idea on how to solve this? Thanks!

This is my Routes:list

```
  GET|POST|HEAD / ................................................................................................................ today › TurnoController@today
  POST       _ignition/execute-solution .......................................... ignition.executeSolution › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › ExecuteSolutionController
  GET|HEAD   _ignition/health-check ...................................................... ignition.healthCheck › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › HealthCheckController
  POST       _ignition/update-config ................................................... ignition.updateConfig › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › UpdateConfigController
  GET|HEAD   admin ................................................................................................................ admin › HomeController@admin
  GET|HEAD   api/user ..........................................................................................................................................
  GET|POST|HEAD calendario ................................................................................................. calendar › TurnoController@calendar
  GET|POST|HEAD grafico/cargar ................................................................................................. upload › TurnoController@upload
  POST       grafico/enviar ............................................................................................... load_csv › UploadController@load_csv
  GET|HEAD   login .................................................................................................. login › Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm
  POST       login .................................................................................................................. Auth\LoginController@login
  POST       logout ....................................................................................................... logout › Auth\LoginController@logout
  GET|HEAD   logout .................................................................................................................................... log-out
  GET|HEAD   password/confirm ................................................................ password.confirm › Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@showConfirmForm
  POST       password/confirm ........................................................................................... Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@confirm
  POST       password/email .................................................................. password.email › Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail
  GET|HEAD   password/reset ............................................................... password.request › Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm
  POST       password/reset ............................................................................... password.update › Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset
  GET|HEAD   password/reset/{token} ................................................................ password.reset › Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm
  GET|POST|HEAD practicas ................................................................................................ practices › TurnoController@practices
  GET|HEAD   register .................................................................................. register › Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm
  POST       register ......................................................................................................... Auth\RegisterController@register
  GET|HEAD   sanctum/csrf-cookie ............................................................. sanctum.csrf-cookie › Laravel\Sanctum › CsrfCookieController@show
  GET|POST|HEAD turnos ......................................................................................................... shifts › TurnoController@shifts
```

Comment: Check your routes with `php artisan route:list` to see if your set your routes correctly

Comment: #Mr. Kenneth, already did that. Everything is correct. I'm adding a new answer with my ugly workaround, but I don't want it like that.

Comment: You might have the same route `/` somewhere. Either check with route:list or manually check everything from top to bottom.

Comment: redirect works for get request but not for your post request, which will have issues later on

Comment: I know it will have issues eventually, that's why it's just a temporary workaround. I checked routes several times. I'm pretty sure there's no conflict on root path. Must be something related to project being stored in a subfolder.

Comment: Can you post your `php artisan route:list` result in the question? Or are there too many of routes already in your project for you to post everything?

Comment: Yep, sure. There it is. Thanks, Kenneth.

Comment: Have you tried to clear route cache? `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: Yes, I do it every time I add or modify routes.

Comment: You might want to check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36476224

Comment: it shows how to get the route name based on url. this way you  can isolate which route is duplicate. But you would need to remove the route you added in your answer before starting.

Comment: Thanks Kenneth. Tested. Only one route as result ('today'), so it seems everything is fine with routes. I still think it is related to running the project with symlink, but I can't find a similar problem on the net.

Comment: If you are doing post request, might as well just write a different uri and method for it. Does not fix the actual problem but at least useable. like `Route::post('/today', TurnoController::class, 'today')->name('today');`

Comment: which will run get on `/` and post on `/today`

Answer (score 0):

By now, the only workaround I figured out is this, but it's ugly as hell.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect()->route('today');
});
Route::match(['GET', 'POST'], '/today', [Controllers\TurnoController::class, 'today'])->name('today');
```

I'd prefer not to use this for too long... :(